# Улучшение страницы справки «Изменение репутации в связи с удалением пользователя»

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Ссылка не текущую версию: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed

Заголовок: Why do I have a reputation change on my reputation page that says 'User was removed'?

---

This message means that a user who voted for one of your posts had their account deleted (either by request or due to violating the network's terms of service). As a result, all of their votes were removed, and the reputation you gained or lost from them was undone. The resultant reputation change could be any amount; it could even be a reputation gain if enough of the removed votes were downvotes. All the reputation changes from a single user's deletion are rolled into a single event in the reputation page labelled "User was removed".

This removal occurs whenever a user is deleted, unless that user had a very high reputation score. Because high-reputation users have usually cast a great many votes, removing all of them could be that much more disruptive to other users. In such cases, the staff use a special deletion that preserves the votes, resulting in no reputation change for those who had been voted on by that user.

Answer (score 1):

Почему в моей учётной записи в разделе «Репутация» изменилась репутация и появилось сообщение «Пользователь был удалён»

---

Это сообщение означает, что учётная запись пользователя, проголосовавшего хотя бы за одно из ваших сообщений, была удалена (по просьбе пользователя или за нарушение правил сети сайтов). В результате все голоса такого пользователя удаляются, а полученная за них репутация отменяется. Изменения в репутации не ограничены количеством баллов; если большая часть удаленных голосов были «против», репутация может даже повыситься. Все изменения репутации, связанные с удалением одного пользователя, объединяются в одно событие, озаглавленное «Пользователь удалён».

Отмена голосов происходит при удалении любого пользователя, кроме тех, кто имеет крайне высокую репутацию. Поскольку такими пользователями обычно было отдано огромное количество голосов, их отмена может существенно отразиться на репутации других участников сообщества. В таких случаях используется специальное удаление, которое сохраняет голоса и не изменяет репутации тех, за или против кого голосовал удалённый пользователь.